# save some information from form with image like state,city,image

Tags: django, forms

```
def seller(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        state = request.POST['state']
        city = request.POST['city']
        full_address = request.POST['fulladdress']
        out = request.POST['out']
        each = seller(state=state,city=city,full_address=full_address,out=out)
        each.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request,'all/seller_input.html')
```

i am tried already this code but a problem is shown  seller() got an unexpected keyword argument 'state'
seller is my table where the all the data store

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view `seller` shadows your model `seller`.

Easiest fix would be to rename your view, e.g. to `register_seller`.

Also, the common convention is to capitalize class names i.e. `Seller`.

If, for whatever reason, you really want to change neither the view nor the class namae, you can also assign an alias during import:

```
from .models import seller as seller_model
...
each = seller_model(...)
```